# Spring boot Circular Dependencies within circular dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, circular-dependency

I am upgrading spring boot version from 2.1.11_RELEASE to 3.0.7 and am facing issue in starting the app. I am working on legacy code so can't make a lot of architectural changes here.

```
@Service
public class RuntimePropertyLoader implements CartCronJob {

    private static final Logger     LOG  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RuntimePropertyLoader.class);
    private static final String     DB_PROP = "DBProp";

    @Autowired
    private DBPropertyDao           propertyDao;
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment env;
    @Autowired
    private AerospikeCatalogClient  aerospikeCatalogService;
    @Autowired
    private AerospikeCartClient     aerospikeCartService;
    @Autowired
    private CartJobConfigLoader     cartJobLoader;
    @Autowired
    private PromoJobConfigLoader    promoJobLoader;
    @Autowired
    private APIErrorMsgLoader       errorMsgLoader;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initLoader() {
        LOG.info("Loading  properties at startup...");
        loadCatalogProperties();
        CartObjectMapper.TAX_LABEL_NAME = env.getProperty("order.amount.tax.label", "GST");
        Arrays.stream(env.getProperty("apiKey.mrp.price.cart", "").split(",")).forEach(v -> CartObjectMapper.MRP_API_KEY.add(v.toUpperCase()));
        cartJobLoader.loadJobConfigs();
        promoJobLoader.loadJobConfigs();
        //userMappingRepository.createIndex();
        errorMsgLoader.loadMsg();
    }

    public void loadCatalogProperties() {

        LOG.info("Loading properties from database...");
        Long offset = 0L;
        Long pageSize = 1000L;
        Map<String, String> propMap;
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        do {
            propMap = propertyDao.getAllProperties(offset, pageSize);
            if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(propMap)) {
                break;
            }
            propMap.forEach((k, v) -> prop.setProperty(k, v));
            offset += pageSize;
        } while (propMap.size() == pageSize);
        MutablePropertySources sources = env.getPropertySources();
        if (sources.contains(DB_PROP)) {
            sources.replace(DB_PROP, new PropertiesPropertySource(DB_PROP, prop));
        } else {
            sources.addLast(new PropertiesPropertySource(DB_PROP, prop));
        }

        setAerospikeValues();
        setCatalogAerospikeValues();
    }

    private void setAerospikeValues() {
        String aerospikeWrtieZone = env.getProperty("aerospike.cart.zone");
        String aerospikeUrlZoneXip = env.getProperty("aerospike.cart.zone_x_ip");
        String aerospikeUrlZoneYip = env.getProperty("aerospike.cart.zone_y_ip");
        String aerospikeUrlZoneXname = env.getProperty("aerospike.cart.zone_x_name");
        String aerospikeUrlZoneYname = env.getProperty("aerospike.cart.zone_y_name");
        String timeoutString = env.getProperty("aerospike.timeout");
        int timeout = 500;
        if (timeoutString != null) {
            timeout = Integer.parseInt(timeoutString);
        }

        Map<String, String> aerospikeZoneIpMap = new HashMap<>();

        LOG.info("aerospikeWrtieZone {}", aerospikeWrtieZone);
        LOG.info("aerospikeUrlZoneXip {}", aerospikeUrlZoneXip);
        LOG.info("aerospikeUrlZoneYip {}", aerospikeUrlZoneYip);
        LOG.info("aerospikeUrlZoneXname {}", aerospikeUrlZoneXname);
        LOG.info("aerospikeUrlZoneYname {}", aerospikeUrlZoneYname);
        LOG.info("timeout {}", timeout);
        aerospikeZoneIpMap.put(aerospikeUrlZoneXname, aerospikeUrlZoneXip);
        aerospikeZoneIpMap.put(aerospikeUrlZoneYname, aerospikeUrlZoneYip);
        AerospikeValues aerospikeValues = new AerospikeValues(aerospikeWrtieZone, aerospikeZoneIpMap, timeout);
        aerospikeCartService.propertyChanged(aerospikeValues);
    }

    private void setCatalogAerospikeValues() {
        String aerospikeWrtieZone = env.getProperty("aerospike.catalog.zone");
        String aerospikeUrlZoneXip = env.getProperty("aerospike.catalog.zone_x_ip");
        String aerospikeUrlZoneYip = env.getProperty("aerospike.catalog.zone_y_ip");
        String aerospikeUrlZoneXname = env.getProperty("aerospike.catalog.zone_x_name");
        String aerospikeUrlZoneYname = env.getProperty("aerospike.catalog.zone_y_name");
        String timeoutString = env.getProperty("aerospike.timeout");
        int timeout = 500;
        if (timeoutString != null) {
            timeout = Integer.parseInt(timeoutString);
        }

        Map<String, String> aerospikeZoneIpMap = new HashMap<>();

        LOG.info("catalogWrtieZone {}", aerospikeWrtieZone);
        LOG.info("catalogUrlZoneXip {}", aerospikeUrlZoneXip);
        LOG.info("catalogUrlZoneYip {}", aerospikeUrlZoneYip);
        LOG.info("catalogUrlZoneXname {}", aerospikeUrlZoneXname);
        LOG.info("catalogUrlZoneYname {}", aerospikeUrlZoneYname);
        LOG.info("timeout {}", timeout);
        aerospikeZoneIpMap.put(aerospikeUrlZoneXname, aerospikeUrlZoneXip);
        aerospikeZoneIpMap.put(aerospikeUrlZoneYname, aerospikeUrlZoneYip);
        AerospikeValues aerospikeValues = new AerospikeValues(aerospikeWrtieZone, aerospikeZoneIpMap, timeout);
        aerospikeCatalogService.propertyChanged(aerospikeValues);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        loadCatalogProperties();
    }

    @Override
    public JobKey getJobKey() {
        return CartJobKeyEnum.PROPERTY_LOADER.getJobKey();
    }

}
```

```
@Service
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class CartJobConfigLoader implements CartCronJob {

    public static final Logger        LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CartJobConfigLoader.class);

    /**
     * Job manager instance which schedules/unschedules job based on the change in job configuration.
     */
    @Autowired
    private CartJobManager            jobManager;

    /** Dao to fetch job configuration from database. */
    @Autowired
    private CartJobConfigDBRepository jobConfigDao;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void loadJobConfigs() {
        for (CartJobConfig jobConfig : jobConfigDao.getAllCronJobs().values()) {
            jobManager.updateJobConfig(jobConfig);
        }
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        LOG.info("Reloading job configs...");
        loadJobConfigs();
    }

    @Override
    public JobKey getJobKey() {
        return CartJobKeyEnum.CRON_LOADER.getJobKey();
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class CartJobManager {
    public static final Logger             LOG                = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CartJobManager.class);

    private final Map<JobKey, CartCronJob> myKeyedJobs        = new HashMap<>();

    private final Set<JobKey>              myDisabledJobs     = new HashSet<>();
    private final Map<JobKey, String>      myJobCronSchedules = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    private Set<CartCronJob>               myRegisteredJobs;

    @Autowired
    private SchedulerFactoryBean           mySchedulerFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initJobManager() {
        LOG.info("Intialising catalog job manager");
        if (myRegisteredJobs == null || myRegisteredJobs.isEmpty()) {
            LOG.info("No job registered with us, nothing to manage here");
            return;
        }

        for (CartCronJob job : myRegisteredJobs) {
            if (myKeyedJobs.put(job.getJobKey(), job) != null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("More than one catalog jobs registered with key: " + job.getJobKey());
            }
        }
    }

    public void unscheduleJob(JobKey jobKey) {
        Scheduler quartzScheduler = mySchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey(jobKey.getName());

        try {
            CronTrigger trigger = (CronTrigger) quartzScheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey);
            if (trigger == null) {
                LOG.info("No trigger already scheduled for job: {}", jobKey);
                return;
            }

            if (quartzScheduler.unscheduleJob(triggerKey)) {
                LOG.info("Successfully unscheduled an existing trigger for job: {}", jobKey);
            }
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            LOG.warn("Failed to unschedule an existing trigger for job: " + jobKey, e);
        }
    }

    public void scheduleJob(JobKey jobKey, String cronExpr, Map<String, String> jobDataMap) {
        CartCronJob job = myKeyedJobs.get(jobKey);
        if (job == null) {
            LOG.warn("No job registered with key: {}, ignoring scheduling request", jobKey);
            return;
        }

        unscheduleJob(jobKey);

        try {
            LOG.info("Scheduling job: {} with cron schedule: {}", jobKey, cronExpr);
            JobDetail quartzJob = JobBuilder.newJob(job.getClass()).withIdentity(jobKey.getName()).build();
            if (null != jobDataMap) {
                quartzJob.getJobDataMap().putAll(jobDataMap);
            }
            CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(new TriggerKey(jobKey.getName())).withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpr)).build();
            mySchedulerFactory.getScheduler().scheduleJob(quartzJob, trigger);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.warn("Failed to schedule the job: {} with cron schedule: {}", job.getJobKey(), cronExpr);
        }
    }

    public void updateJobConfig(CartJobConfig jobConfig) {
        JobKey jobKey = jobConfig.getJobKey();
        boolean isEnabled = jobConfig.isEnabled();
        String cronStr = jobConfig.getCronSchedule();
        Map<String, String> jobDataMap = getJobDataMapFromJson(jobConfig.getJobContext());

        if (myDisabledJobs.contains(jobKey) && isEnabled) {
            myDisabledJobs.remove(jobKey);
            myJobCronSchedules.put(jobKey, cronStr);
            LOG.info("Enabling job: {}", jobKey);
            scheduleJob(jobKey, cronStr, jobDataMap);
            return;
        }

        if (!isEnabled && myDisabledJobs.add(jobKey)) {
            LOG.info("Disabling job: {}", jobKey);
            unscheduleJob(jobKey);
            return;
        }

        String oldCronStr = myJobCronSchedules.put(jobKey, cronStr);
        if (!cronStr.equals(oldCronStr)) {
            LOG.info("Cron schedule changed for job: {} to: {} from: {}", oldCronStr, jobKey, cronStr);
            scheduleJob(jobKey, cronStr, jobDataMap);
        }
    }

    public String getCronSchedule(CartJobKeyEnum jobkey) {
        return myJobCronSchedules.get(jobkey.getJobKey());

    }

    private Map<String, String> getJobDataMapFromJson(String jobContextJson) {
        Map<String, String> map = null;
        try {
            if (!StringUtils.hasText(jobContextJson)) {
                return null;
            }
            map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jobContextJson, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Failed to parse json {}", jobContextJson, ex);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

```
public interface CartCronJob extends Job {
    public JobKey getJobKey();
}
```

I have added Lazy annotations and am confused how to use @PostConstruct or getter/setter injections. Here, **`myRegisteredJobs` is a set of `CartCronJob` and `RuntimePropertyLoader`  and `CartJobConfigLoader` both implement `CartCronJob.`**

[Circular dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojd1f.png)

I added all Lazy annotations in all combinations but nothing worked.